# how to add new data to existing list in firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

here is the firebase console

[image]

when I tried to add new value using this code

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userCollection').doc(user!.uid).set({
      'purchased-id': [oldPurcasedID]
    }, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

and here is the getPurchaseID function

```
getPurchasedID() async {
    DocumentSnapshot pathData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('userCollection')
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get();

    if (pathData.exists) {
      Map<String, dynamic>? fetchDoc = pathData.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;

      final purchasedIdMap = await fetchDoc?['purchased-id'];

      print('purchased map value : $purchasedIdMap');

      return purchasedIdMap;
    }
    return [];
  }
```

it is replacing the '0'th list value,
how do I add new list under this

I also tried `SetOptions(merge: true));`. but this didn't help

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit clearly? What did you expect to happen and what actually happened, with examples? What is there inside `oldPurcasedId`? Also to update an array field you can use arrayUnion as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Comment: @Prabir hey, i got what the problem is, but I did update the question , take a look :)

Comment: Your question is still not clear. I asked what is inside `oldPurchaseId`. Maybe you are getting it from the `getPurchaseId()` function and modifying the array somewhere in your code and setting that again for the `purchased-id' field. If `oldPurchaseId` is an array it will replace the old array for the `purchased-id` field. Anyway, if you got the problem can you explain it a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Use `update` instead `set`, which overwrites a document.